# Request help me sort out the issue in the following code:

Tags: php, pdo

This code is to edit records / entries in the table titled 'tickets' with id being primary key, while 'serialno' is the serial number of the ticket.  Rest of the entries like member_id, id-off and id_emp are indices from other tables named 'members', 'employees', and 'offices'. Here is the message that I get when executing this script:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\luckypool\updateserial.php on line 67

```
<?php

require "config.php";
require "common.php";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $ticket =[
      "id"        => $_POST['id'],
      "serialno"  => $_POST['serialno'],
      "draw"      => $_POST['draw'],
      "member_id" => $_POST['member_id'],
      "id_off"    => $_POST['id_off'],
      "id_emp"    => $_POST['id_emp'],
      "date"      => $_POST['date']
    ];

    $sql = "UPDATE tickets 
            SET id = :id, 
              serialno = :serialno, 
              draw = :draw, 
              member_id = :member_id,
              id_off = :id_off,
              id_emp = :id_emp,
              date = :date 
            WHERE id = :id";

  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute($ticket);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE id = :id";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':id', $id);
    $statement->execute();

    $ticket = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
    exit;
}
?>

<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) : ?>
    <blockquote><?php echo escape($_POST['serialno']); ?> successfully updated.</blockquote>
<?php endif; ?>

<h2>Edit Ticket Record</h2>

<form method="post">
    <?php foreach ($ticket as $key => $value) : ?>
      <label for="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($key); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo escape($value); ?>" <?php echo ($key === 'id' ? 'readonly' : null); ?>>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: I assume that your line 67 is `<?php foreach ($ticket as $key => $value) : ?>`, but your variable `$ticket` is set only if `$_GET['id']` is available.

Comment: use isset($tickets) before foreach loop like this if(isset($tickets)) { foreach ($ticket as $key => $value) //your code }

Answer (score 0):

```
use isset($tickets) before foreach loop

    <form method="post">
        <?php 
         if (isset($ticket) && is_array($tickets)) {
           foreach ($ticket as $key => $value) : ?>
             <label for="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo ucfirst($key); ?></label>
             <input type="text" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" id="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo escape($value); ?>" <?php echo ($key === 'id' ? 'readonly' : null); ?>>
        <?php 
           endforeach; 
         }
         ?> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Khan Farman, thanks a lot for the answer.  However, it didn't work.  Even with the change it returns the same error message:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\luckypool\updateserial.php on line 69

Comment: ok then $tickets is set but is not an array, i have edited my answer with one extra condition, try it

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I just discovered that I was using wrong parameter to bind the pages:  I was using 'serialno' instead of 'id' at the pages from where i was coming for the edit.  Indeed grateful.